# LaTeX failed to compile ,file again and again

Tags: r, windows, latex, r-markdown, tinytex

I am trying to knit R Markdown to PDF and it doesn't work. I installed the package "tinytex" and try everything I can. I receive the following error code:

```
! warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf/web2c.
! ...<U+00BB><U+0084>????\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:935: ...<U+00BB><U+0084>????\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
! Running the command C:\Users<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt

! The command name is C:\Users<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt
! warning: kpathsea: mktexfmt output `c:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt' instead of a filename.

! warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf/web2c.
! ...<U+00BB><U+0084>????\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:935: ...<U+00BB><U+0084>????\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
! Running the command C:\Users<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt

! The command name is C:\Users<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt
! warning: kpathsea: mktexfmt output `c:/Users/<U+00BB><U+01BA><U+00A3><U+00B7>/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt' instead of a filename.
```

Consider that I am in China ,so I download the Tinytex.zip from gtihub but when I try to install it :

```
tinytex:::install_prebuilt(pkg="D:/latex/TinyTeX.zip")
output:Warning: conflicting [pdf]tex program found on the system path in C:\Users\禄脝潞拢路氓\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32; not fixable in user mode.
```

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask>

Comment: It worked when I changed my user's name. Latex failed to compile when Chinese in the path.
Sorry for my poor knowledge.